# Controller Spec is using FakeApplication, but can't load test configuration

Tags: scala, playframework

My HomeControllerSpec looks like:

```
@RunWith(ClassOf[JUnitRunner])
class HomeControllerSpec extends Specification {

  "HomeController" should {

      object FakeGuiceGlobal extends play.api.GlobalSettings {
          private lazy val injector = {
            Guice.createInjector(new GuiceServicesModule)
          }

          override def getControllerInstance[A](clazz: Class[A]) = {
            injector.getInstance(clazz)
          }

          override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classloader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
            val modeSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("application.test.conf"))
            super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig, path, classloader, mode)
          }
        }


        "index" in {
          running(FakeApplication(withGlobal = Some(FakeGuiceGlobal))) {

            // test here

          }

        }

   }

}
```

For some reason it doesn't load the `application.test.conf` file, it is still reading from the default `application.conf` file.

Why isn't it reading from the test config file?

If it cant' read the file, why am I not seeing an error if the file path is not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Play's `GlobalSettings.onLoadConfig` method states:

> Called just after configuration has been loaded, to give the
>   application an opportunity to modify it.

Providing an override of that method does not give you the opportunity to specify a different 
configuration to load, only to modify it. When you use the ++ operator, it is defined in play like this:

```
def ++(other: Configuration): Configuration = {
    Configuration(other.underlying.withFallback(underlying))
}
```

Note how it invokes `other.underlying.withFallback` which is a call in the embedded Typesafe Config object. Essentially, the configuration from `application.test.conf` **is** loaded and used as the *fallback* for configuration values. Any value you had in the original file is given priority during lookup. Values that only occur in `application.test.conf` will be found.

*FYI: The "credible source" here is the Play code itself.*

Comment: Great thanks.  So the only way to provide a different config file is via the command line?  Oh, maybe if I delete the application.conf it won't find the file, and then look for whatever I put in the override.

Comment: The technique that myborobudur will allow you to use a different config file. If you delete application.conf then Play will likely give you a warning or use some internal default. You might want to read the Configuration class documentation as all the options are spelled out there.

Comment: One thing to note:  It doesn't seem to be overriding what is in my application.conf, it is suppose to update the config value if I override it in onLoadCOnfig

Comment: The onLoadConfig function expects you to return the new configuration. What you returned was the super.onLoadConfig value. I'm not sure what that does but if you just returned modeSpecificConfig it would probably give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *override* the default location when you execute your tests:

```
-Dconfig.resource=./application.test.conf
```

Make sure the file path is correct.

Comment: Why doesn't it work when I am overriding the onLoadConfig method though for fakeApplication?

Comment: if the file path isn't correct, shouldn't I get an error then?